# Highcharts. Pie chart. DataLabels formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a pie chart. And I need to format DataLabels in someway. So I use:

```
    dataLabels: {
                 useHTML : true,
                 formatter: function () {
                     if(this.point.id == 'razr') {                                       
                     return '<div><b>' + this.point.y + '</b></div><div style="left: -140px; text-align: center; position: absolute"><b>sum is:<br/>' + this.point.summ + ' </b></div>';
                } else return '<b>' + this.point.y + '<b>';
             }
}
```

And what I got:

[image: pie]

My problem is here `style="left: -140px;`. The position is static. I can't find any way to position my `sum label` at the center of a green point of a chart. I've been searching the properties of a point (like `plotX`, `graphic` attr), nothing helps. If I remove `style="left: -140px;` datalabel will moves to the right. How can I get coordinates of my green point?

Comment: if possible share us fiddle link

Comment: @PandiyanCool Thank you, but my project is difficult. Chart div located at `header.php`, chart data sends from `request.php` to `functions.js` via `jsonPost`... So I guess it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, it's not easy. I see two possible solutions:

1) Easy (but dirty workaround): create second pie chart under the first one with the same values, but render just one label. Then the second pie chart can have `dataLabel` inside the slice.

2) Hard (more generic solution): calculate required top/left offsets. It's hard because you don't know bounding box of the label. I suggest to set fixed `width`+`height` for that part of the label - so you can find center of that label's part. Then calculate position using `series.center` and `point.labelPos` arrays. These are inner options and can change between versions, so keep an eye on these options before upgrading. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zwb5toe9/2/

```
            dataLabels: {
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    var point = this.point,
                        width = 50,
                        height = 50,
                        series = point.series,
                        center = series.center,               //center of the pie
                        startX = point.labelPos[4],           //connector X starts here
                        endX = point.labelPos[0] + 5,         //connector X ends here
                        left =  -(endX - startX + width / 2), //center label over right edge
                        startY = point.labelPos[5],           //connector Y starts here
                        endY = point.labelPos[1] - 5,         //connector Y ends here
                        top =  -(endY - startY + height / 2); //center label over right edge


                    // now move inside the slice:
                    left += (center[0] - startX)/2;
                    top += (center[1] - startY)/2;

                    if (point.id == 'razr') {
                        console.log(this);
                        return '<div><b>' + point.y + '</b></div><div style="width: ' + width + 'px; left:' + left + 'px;top:' + top + 'px; text-align: center; position: absolute"><b>sum is:<br/>' + point.summ + ' </b></div>';
                    } else return '<b>' + point.y + '<b>';
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can we use ES6 (arrow) function in formatter? formatter: () => {
}? How to access point object?

Comment: You can use it, but you will lose access to `this.point`, because the context will change. The only argument in formatter is a dataLabels options object, so with the arrow function, you can not access the point object.

Comment: Yes Pawel, I am facing same issue. I have posted a fresh question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66149782/highchart-pie-chart-de-structure-datalabels-and-define-custom-formatter