# Highcharts pie dropdown showing labels inside the pie

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I want to show 2 data labels inside pie charts with drill-down. I know this is possible by overlaying 2 pie with different data labels. However, in the drill down, it's only showing 1 data labels, which is the last one I put (the first data label is being ignored by highcharts).

Here is my attempt:
[https://jsfiddle.net/firstlutfi/a3v3mhef/](https://jsfiddle.net/firstlutfi/a3v3mhef/41/)

```
    $('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 0
    },
            plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            size: '80%',
            cursor: 'pointer',
        data: [{
            name: 'Jakarta',
            y: 7000000,
            drilldown: 'jakarta_sales'
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            y: 5000000,
        },
        ]
        },
    },
    series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
        name: 'Sales Details',
        colorByPoint: true,
                    dataLabels: {
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            connectorWidth: 1,
            distance: -30,
            connectorColor: '#000000',
            format: '{point.percentage:.2f}%'
        },
    },{
                    type: 'pie',
        name: 'Sales Details',
        colorByPoint: true,
                    dataLabels: {
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            connectorWidth: 1,
            distance: 30,
            connectorColor: '#000000',
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>:<br/> ' + this.y + ' ';
            }
        }
    }],
    exporting: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    drilldown: {
        series: [
                    {
            name: 'Jakarta Sales',
            id: 'jakarta_sales',
            data: [
                {name:'Car Brand A', 
                dataLabels: {
                  verticalAlign: 'top',
                  enabled: true,
                  color: '#000000',
                  connectorWidth: 1,
                  distance: -30,
                  connectorColor: '#000000',
                  format:'{point.percentage:.2f}%'
                },
                y:800000},
                                    {name:'Car Brand B', y:400000},
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Jakarta Sales',
            id: 'jakarta_sales',
            data: [
                {name:'Car Brand A', 
                dataLabels: {
                  verticalAlign: 'top',
                  enabled: true,
                  color: '#000000',
                  connectorWidth: 1,
                  distance: 30,
                  connectorColor: '#000000',
                  format:'{point.name}:<br/> {point.y}'
                },
                y:800000},
                                    {name:'Car Brand B', y:400000},
            ]
        },]
    }
});
```

Update:
[image: Outer part of the chart]

click on the jakarta data, and you'll get this
[image: click on the jakarta data, and you'll get this]

The result that i want is to have 2 labels in the drilldown. one is the amount (on the outside of the pie), and the percentage (inside the pie).

Is anyone know how to use 2 data labels (inside and outside) every chart including the drill down?
Thank you.

Comment: check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/zzo5zhfe/ , is problem resolved

Comment: what is _2 data labels (inside and outside)_ can you explain

Comment: @Deep3015 i updated my question with images so you can see the difference

Comment: It seems _I know this is possible by overlaying 2 pie with different data labels._ not working in drilldown as you said

Answer (score 0):

I see you use workaround to render multiple-labels per point by using two pie charts. Problem with that solution is.. you can not drilldown from one pie chart to multiple pie charts (ID's are unique).

Reminder: there is also another solution: [Highcharts. Pie chart. DataLabels formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075250/highcharts-pie-chart-datalabels-formatter)

In your case, try async-drilldown (see details in [drilldown event](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown)) instead:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a3v3mhef/77/

Snippets:

- create the event:

  ```
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      drilldown: function (e) {
        this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, drilldownSeries[0]);
        this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, drilldownSeries[1]);

        this.applyDrilldown();
      }
    }
  },
  ```
- enable drilldown on a point:

  ```
  data: [{
    name: 'Jakarta',
    y: 7000000,
    drilldown: true // just enabled, no ID
  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    y: 5000000,
  }]
  ```
- setup series references:

  ```
  var drilldownSeries = [{ ... }, { ... }];
  ```